# is it ok to change the value from outside a Map?

Tags: java, oop

So i have a code snippet here. I go this issue while i was discussing some code  with  my friend

```
Map<Integer , List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer , List<String>>();
List<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
myMap.put(45,list);
List<String> lst = myMap.get(45);
lst.add("String1");
lst.add("String2");
lst.add("String3");
System.out.println(myMap.get(45));
```

My question here is.
-> If its ok to modify the list outside the map through another reference? I am asking from OOP design point of view.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly OK.

Comment: You should have a look at Google Guava's Multimap classes - they deal with a lot of the boilerplate associated with Map<K, Collection<V>> kind of relations.

Answer (score 2):

That is completely ok, *IMHO*

When you write

```
List<String> lst = myMap.get(45);
```

Still it is refering to the value in the `map`, for the key `45`.

Once you get the value(`reference` to the `list`), It's up to you what you are doing with it.

Answer (score 2):

> If its ok to modify the list outside the map through another reference? I am asking from OOP design point of view.

It really depends on the context in which you're modifying it. If you plan on doing this a lot, with a lot of different values, then you're quickly going to find yourself with very confusing code that is difficult to debug and to follow.

BUT, in your example, you first load it from the map, then you edit it. It's completely clear that the data is coming from your `Map` object. Provided you make it clear with comments and documentation, especially when you're passing this reference between other methods, this isn't bad practise at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is OK, provided that you take care of any potential synchronizations; e.g. if there are multiple threads that might be modifying the map and / or the list.

You might be confusing this with the case where you modify a *key* object.  That is distinctly NOT ok if the modification breaks the hash table invariants; e.g.

- if it causes either the key's hashcode to change, or
- if it causes the key to give a different result when compared with some other key used in the table.

---

> I am asking from OOP design point of view.

I'd say that OO design is neutral on this issue.  You are using a Java interface (i.e. `Map`) that doesn't take control of the values.  You are not violating encapsulation because the values are not encapsulated by the `Map` abstraction.

Whether this is sound design from the application perspective depends on the overall design.  We can't make a judgement one way or another without understanding the context.

Answer (score 0):

Every reference has a scope, it is your take(based on your requirement) whether you want the Map to be accessed through multiple reference or through a single reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK.
After you have added numbers to the list in lines 5-7 in your code snippet, and then you get the list from the map again in line 8, the list you get from the map will have the extra numbers you just added.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do with the list and what your requirements are.

I'd say it is ok-ish but it might be better to encapsulate that in another object.
Consider the question what to do with empty lists, should they be removed or kept?

Encapsulation would allow you to ensure that empty lists are removed, since the user would then only access the wrapper, not the list directly.

Btw, with `HashMap` you *have* to change the list outside the map ;)

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is mutable. It is resizeable and keeps the same reference after modification. To have immutable list you should use following code.

```
 List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

If you define list above way, than you can't modify it.

Comment: OP is not asking how to prevent to modify, Asking is it ok ? `If its ok to modify the list outside the map through another reference?`

Comment: I have seen what OP is asking. This is reference answer if OP wants to get unmodifiable List.